# How to be sure of writing the whole string to file at once in C++

Tags: c++, ostream

I want to do an "inter-process communication" with a file in the middle. producer writes messages to the file and the consumer reads it.

**my question is about the producer.**

assume this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Create and open a "file in the middle" IPC
  ofstream messagefile("filename.txt");

  // Write to the file
  messagefile << "Files can be tricky, hope you are reading all of this string at once\n";

  // Close the file
  MyFile.close();
}
```

Is there any risk that buffer flush (at any level of OS or std lib) flushes this string in more than one part?
I want to ensure that consumer processes read the whole message in one shot. What do you suggest?

I know the consumer can wait for a specific character like "\n", but my question is about the producer.

Comment: For that small text, it should all fit in a single buffer. But if you have a much larger text then you will have a problem with possibly multiple flushes. You could always use OS-specific *file locking* to prevent other processes from opening the file until you unlock its access.

Comment: It can't be realized in a reliable way. Make some kind of protocol `<70>Files can be tricky, hope you are reading all of this string at once\n`.

Comment: I think for inter process communication you should use sockets, not files.

Comment: Minor point: you don’t need to call `MyFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: This is unspecified by the C++ standard. On Linux, with a local filesystem, I will expect each individual `write()` system call to be atomic.

Comment: Yes there is a risk and there is no reliable way to prevent it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think `write()` is guaranteed atomic in Linux (or any other time-share system). Not in the sense of "all this (of nothing of it) goes to disk". If a system crash occurs, you may lose the last part of the data. `write()` is supposed to be atomic between processes and threads (if two actors write "at the same time" to the same target, their data should'n overlap) (but see [https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)).

Comment: You will need to use some kind of signalling to indicate that the file is being written to and when it is finished.  You really don't want to tasks to write to the file at the same time, -- undefined behavior.

Comment: I also suggest some kind of signalling or event to tell the *other* process that there is data in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned about the possible loss of information because of a system crash, I would suggest you to use `ostream::flush` plus some kind of operating system dependent call for really flushing the I/O buffers to disk (like `sync()` on Unix systems).

If you're just concerned about the IPC protocol (that is, you just want to avoid reading partial messages), the use of a terminator should be enough. Two *different* separate "marks" (beginning and end) may be useful in some situations.

I assume you just have one writer active at a time.

Comment: Or, regarding the possible data-loss situation, just try to write more frequently and in smaller chunks. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that finally, I should do some protocol. but for now, I hope I can find a reliable way from the producer side only